# I have a syntax error with my update query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am trying to update a column by summing up data from another column in another table but I don't understand why I keep getting syntax error.

```
UPDATE [Reference No - Quotation] RQ
INNER JOIN [Customer- Quotation] CQ ON CQ.ReferenceID = RQ.ReferenceID
SET RQ.[Total Cost (Monthly)] =SUM(CQ.[Total Amount]) 
WHERE = RQ.[ReferenceID] = CQ.[ReferenceID];
```

Comment: MySQL or Access ? Please use proper tags

Comment: remove `=` after `WHERE`

Comment: @4dmonster tks for pointing that out. Now, it tells me that the query does not include  [Total cost (Monthly)] as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: This looks more like sqlserver than mysql - unless you are attempting to convert to mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY` which is needed for `SUM` makes query read only. Use temporary tables or domain functions(`DSum` and others) or such dirty MS Access hack:

```sql
UPDATE [Reference No - Quotation] RQ
INNER JOIN [Customer- Quotation] CQ ON CQ.ReferenceID = RQ.ReferenceID
SET RQ.[Total Cost (Monthly)] = 0 
WHERE RQ.[ReferenceID] = CQ.[ReferenceID];
```

```sql
UPDATE [Reference No - Quotation] RQ
INNER JOIN [Customer- Quotation] CQ ON CQ.ReferenceID = RQ.ReferenceID
SET RQ.[Total Cost (Monthly)] = RQ.[Total Cost (Monthly)] + CQ.[Total Amount])
WHERE RQ.[ReferenceID] = CQ.[ReferenceID];
```

Answer (score -2):

This was wrong, due to correcting comments:

As I know, Access needs to be both tables to be modifiable, when using `UPDATE` query, so using `INNER JOIN` leads to be query results to be read-only. In this case I use temp tables:

- create temp table from your `INNER JOIN` query
- use temp table as updating source

Comment: True, but my expirience is different. May because it was MS 2003, maybe